# debian lenny box, how can I check for apache and mysql installs?

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

debian lenny box, how can I check for apache and mysql installs?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about the context in which you need this information?  Can we assume that the system only has packages that where installed via apt?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -l |egrep '(apache|mysql)'`